# Shall we allow cheating the voting system?

Tags: discussion

No question, there are quite few people who pump their reputation by upvoting for their questions/answers using different accounts. I don't think it's the appropriate behavior. Do you?

Comment: I think there's a SE-wide system in place to deal with that.

Comment: From what can be seen it's not very efficient, is it?

Comment: I don't really know and don't particularly care. If it isn't, it should be discussed on SE's meta, not here. How do you propose we handle the situation, anyway? Witch hunts?

Comment: I propose that 1. people stop doing that (everybody can be cooperative as long as they want to) 2. by having access to the real data the abuse can be clearly seen, question here is what it takes to get there; 3. once abuse is detected the appropriate actions should take place; Is this a bad idea?

Comment: I doubt anybody willing to invest time to inflate their rep is going to stop doing it just because it's a scummy thing to do. I don't believe mods have access to the sort of information required to detect such actions anyway, which makes it a feature request for SE inc.

Comment: I say, this question is ludicrous, because duh!, that is why. In that it is rethorical, and not at all constructive. Firstly, not many would think of it as appropriate behaviour (hence duh!). Secondly, it is very accusatory without any evidence. Thirdly, who would go through all this trouble anyway (in order to get accounts to be able to upvote, one would divert points from original account which is counter-productive)?

Comment: @kotekzot Moderators actually do have the means to detect voting rings and fraudulent votes.

Comment: @AnnaLear do you mean diamond mods, elected mods or 10k mods?

Comment: @kotekzot Diamond mods (both protem and elected). Right now this site doesn't have moderators, so we (the community team at Stack Exchange) act as your moderators in the meantime.

Comment: @AnnaLear cool, good to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is, of course, not allowed on any of our sites. This is not a matter of individual site policy.

Moderators are equipped with tools to detect invalid votes (both up and down) and any such activity is gonna result in a suspension.

Now, that's assuming you're speaking hypothetically. If not and if you have suspicions about specific users, please flag their posts for moderator attention, leave us a note and we'll investigate.

Comment: this is the first sane answer, thank you very much